# Find $\arctan(x) + \arctan(y)$ in terms of $\arctan((x + y)/(1 - xy))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

Find $\arctan(x) + \arctan(y)$ in terms of $\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$.

---

I want to essentially prove this equation given in the textbook:
$$ \arctan(x) + \arctan(y) = 
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right),  &\text{if } xy\lt 1 \\[1.5ex]
\pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right),  &\text{if } x\gt 0, y\lt 0\text{ and } xy \gt 1 \\[1.5ex]
-\pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right),  &\text{if } x\lt 0, y\lt 0\text{ and } xy \gt 1 \\
\end{cases}$$

> By now i have proven the third case where $x<0$ and $y<0$ as follows:
>   Let $A=\arctan(x)$ and $B=\arctan(y)$, and $A+b=\alpha$. If $-\pi<A+B<-\pi/2$, then $A<0,B<0 \iff x<0,y<0$. As $A+B<-\pi/2$ for the third case, thus:
>   $$A<-(\pi/2+B) \\
> \arctan(x)<-(\pi/2+\arctan(y)) \\
> \because y<0, \qquad \therefore -(\pi/2+\arctan(y))=\arctan(1/y) \\
> \therefore \arctan(x) < \arctan(1/y) \implies x<1/y \\
> \therefore xy>1
> $$
>   I am specifically not able to find such a condition in $x$ and $y$ for the first case, that is the case where $xy < 1$. How do i prove it using a similar approach to mine? (That is no differentiation, only trigonometry). I tried using the inequality $A+B\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, but am stuck.

Comment: See  the Article $240,$ Ex$-5$ of  http://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog

Comment: What a coincidence! This is exactly the question which I asked an hour ago! I think lab's comment has solved my query. Thanks @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @Tim Ah! It didn't appear in my "questions that may already have an answer" list. Anyways, if someone else stumbles across this one, here is a link to that [question](math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724348/what-is-arctanx-arctany).

Comment: And yes, thank you @labbhattacharjee for that link!

Comment: @FreezingFire You had asked the question first is what I meant! Now my question has an answer, but no answer was posted here! Cheers!